# Finding Kernel of Polynomial Ring Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have the homomorphism $$F : C[x,y] \to C[x] \times C[y],\space  F(p(x,y)) = (p(x,0), p(0,y))$$

The kernel is clearly $\langle xy \rangle$.

If I want to show that $\langle xy \rangle = \ker(F)$ I need to use double inclusion.

First : To show that $\langle xy \rangle$ is in $\ker(F)$.  I take a $p(x,y)$ generated by $\langle xy \rangle$, so $p(x,y) = xyq(x,y)$ ;   $p(x,0) = 0$ and $p(0,y) = 0$. Therefore $(p(x,0),(0,y)) = (0,0)$ and this is in $\ker(F)$.

My trouble begins with the second part, when I need to show that $\ker(F)$ is included in $\langle xy \rangle$

I would appreciate some advice on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: So, the kernel is **clearly** the ideal generated by $xy$, but you failed to prove this!

Comment: Haha, clearly in a intuitive way

Comment: Anyway, $p(x,0)=0$ iff $p\in (y)$ and $p(0,y)=0$ iff $p\in(x)$. Now you have to show that $(x)\cap(y)=(xy)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha\in \ker(F)$ not divisible by $xy$.
It implies that $\alpha = Qxy+ax+by+c$ such that not all of $a,b,c$ are 0.
Since $\alpha(x,0)=0$, $ax+c=0$, which at $0$ implies $c=0$, and at $1$ implies $a=0$
Since $\alpha(y,0)=0$, $by+c=0 \implies by=0$ which  at $1$ implies $b=0$ which is a contradiction.